# In angularJs , how to modify auto-complete to show recently used items on top?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, autocomplete

I have used https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/autocomplete in many projects. 
Many users prefer to see "Most used items" or "Recently used items" on top of the list. 
Each item would have some sort of a "rank" or "use-count", but should be per-user.

This behavior is expected when the list opens and when the user starts to type few characters. 
Any suggestions please ?

**Update**
Use case: a dropdown list of a cities. The user types 'B', the list of options might be:

- Bakersfield California.
- Baltimore Maryland.
- Baton Rouge Louisiana.
- Birmingham Alabama.
- **Boston** Massachusetts.
- Buffalo New York.

The user selects '**Boston**' ... so next time the list opens and types 'B', Boston should be the first entry like so:

- **Boston** Massachusetts.  <----- User preference
- Bakersfield California.
- Baltimore Maryland.
- Baton Rouge Louisiana.
- Birmingham Alabama.
- Buffalo New York.

## **(Per user preferences) Client Side or Server Side**

Using client side storage of user preference is simple and straight forward, but with a restriction of being only on the device currently used.

While server side preference, works across devices, but requires more complex work, especially when there is multiple drop down lists.

Comment: You could use JavaScript to implement such logic.

Comment: You know I think that answer ~ question. So store most used items in db .

Comment: I would guess the downvotes are coming from the lack of use case detail.  Please supply a use case to fit the question to a better format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question we would store something like this in localStorage.  We do that on the last preference that a customer has on the previous selection in our product dropdown.  If the user clears all of their cache, then it's lost.  Storing it in a database would give persistence, but more overhead, and more code.

If it's a small set of data that is the same for all users, then you could create a cache that gets selected from a service or use the [HTML 5 datalist](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/creating-autocomplete-dropdowns-datalist-element).

There are close to 300 cities in the USA with populations of 100k or more, I would think that will suffice for the US.  For this use case, since you are adding in languages and multiple countries, you will need a data store for all the values, such as a database.  There is a angularjs module called [anguarlar-localStorage](https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage) as well, but I don't know if 
it will scale with your dataset, depending on the number of countries/languages, but it's an option if you want to keep everything client-side.

Comment: I assume that using localStorage is better for "per-user" lists. So, the browser loads all entries from server, then ranks the items based on user "local preferences" of most used items, before displaying them out.
Each time an entry is selected, the "local" items rank gets incremented.

Comment: I assume server side "preferences" would require more complex work